# Get unstructured data from excel sheets into 1 new file

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm trying to be pointed into the right direction of finding a solution of an interesting request I've gotten recently.

An excel file was given to me, with 1 sheet per day, so the year file has 365 sheets, named based on their date.

Now the interesting and also annoying part is that the sheet contains roughly 15 tables, which are not formatted as tables but only visually. See the example here:

[image: Example of the data]

The desired format is this:

TABLE NAME --  NAME --  VALUE1  --  VALUE2 --  VALUE3 --  SHEETNAME

Luckily the source format is the same on every sheet. My question is, does anyone know a good method to create a new excel file that takes all this data and combines it into 1 sheet. Which software? Language etc.

So essentially it would be saying, use cell/row X5&&cell/row Y4 as column 1, cell/rowxxx as column 2 etc. (from all sheets available, combined)

Then what I'd want is to import said data and have it transformed/loaded into 1 big new table as described. I previously used pandas dataframe and tabular to merge PDF tables into 1 but these were already actual tables of itself and thus easier. These are basically just cells, visually shown as tables making this quite a nightmare.

Would highly appreciate any creative ideas.

Comment: I would probably have gone with VBA. Write a proc that handles a single sheet and apply it in a loop over all sheets.You know you will have output 6 columns and a quick last row calc for each sheet will give you the number of rows in order to pre-size an array to populate. You could get clever, but if you know each table block in the sheet is 4 columns wide, and that there are two blocks of tables (column wise), I would use Range.Find to get first "Table*"  then start looping rows, using Table* and Total as start stops. When hit end of one column block,

Comment: use .Find on next column block i.e. the 4 columns right offset, to get start row for adjacent columns block and repeat same process...... all the time writing the relevant info into an array. Now, more efficient would be to read each used range in the sheet into an array first and loop that rather than the actual sheet but you'd then need to handle possible jagged array.

Comment: *_Jagged array in reality masked as regular array by used range._ For python, you might consider the, IMO, complicated [tidyxl package](https://youtu.be/PYAxTuPk1mc). If you are particularly good at M then maybe you could do something similar to what I outlined in VBA but there would be some M coding rather than just button clicking with M generated in background. And as always, where possible, with X,Y problems >> fix the source. Get the data supplier to provide in flat file format